# Oracle client requires parentheses around column names?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle

I was recently asked to migrate our MSSQL database to an Oracle one.

I'm using the old-traditional way to execute sql queries.

for some reason, unknown to me, Oracle requires me to put parentheses around column names (why?)
Is there a workaround for this?

The following code will fail because of the parentheses (used to work well under MSSQL)

```
using (var msq = new OracleConnection(sConnectionString))
{
    msq.Open();
    OracleCommand msc = msq.CreateCommand();
    msc.CommandText = @"SELECT level_1,element_id FROM tnuot_menu_tree 
                       WHERE level_1 IN 
                           (SELECT mt.level_1 FROM tnuot_menu_tree mt 
                               WHERE mt.element_id IN
                               (SELECT element_tree_id FROM tnuot_menu_elements 
                                WHERE UPPER(element_link) LIKE :url)) 
                       AND level_2 = 0 AND level_3 = 0";

    msc.Parameters.Add("url", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    msc.Parameters["url"].Value = "%" + sName.ToUpper();
    OracleDataReader mrdr = msc.ExecuteReader();

    while (mrdr.Read())
    {
        sResult.arDirectResult.Add(mrdr[0].ToString());
        sResult.arDirectResult.Add(mrdr[1].ToString());
        break;
    }

    msc.Dispose();
    mrdr.Dispose();
    msq.Close();
}
```

Instead, in the VS server explorer, the last query gets 'translated' to

```
SELECT "level_1", "element_id"
FROM "tnuot_menu_tree"
WHERE ("level_1" IN
    (SELECT "level_1" FROM "tnuot_menu_tree" mt
     WHERE ("element_id" IN
         (SELECT "element_tree_id" FROM "tnuot_menu_elements"
          WHERE (UPPER("element_link") LIKE '%DEFAULT.ASPX'))))) 
AND ("level_2" = 0) AND ("level_3" = 0)
```

Which works well.

Any ideas on how to get rid of this nasty task?

Comment: If you execute the first code-block, does it work?

Comment: @HansKesting, nope - I get 'ORA-00942: Table or view does not exist.'

Comment: I think the table was created with case sensitivity hence you would need the quotes to query it, `"tnuot_menu_elements"` ensures the case sensitivity. sad its a result of `CREATE TABLE "tnuot_menu_elements" ..`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly, it isn't the brackets that are necessary; it's the double quotes. This is Oracle's equivalent of SQLServer's use of square brackets - it may be necessary here because the tables have been created with lower-case names, but without the double quotes Oracle automatically converts names to upper-case.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference between your first and second query are the quotes (and not the parentheses). The additional parentheses aren't needed. They seem to be a strange artifact of the VS server explorer.

Contrary to popular belief, Oracle is case-sensitive. The column names `level_1` and `LEVEL_1` are different. If your column and table names are all upper-case, case won't matter because Oracle converts all unquoted identifiers in SQL statements to upper-case.

But if your column and tables names use lower case letters, you must put the column names in double quotes to have the proper casing retained.