# Writing a SQL Query into VBA using a IFF statement, Get missing expression error

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I have been trying to figure this out for days, and not having any luck. I am trying to write a SQL line command inside of VBA.

I am getting the "ORA-00936: misssing expresson error"

```
strSql4 = "SELECT FWLOTID, ENDDATETIME, ENDCODE, DRAW, IIF([ENDCODE]=""6"", ""MSNAG"",""0"") "    ' Or ENDCODE='10' Or ENDCODE='11' Or ENDCODE='12' Or ENDCODE='14'"

strSql3 = "FROM EVENTS.ODSWIND WHERE ENDDATETIME > to_date('" & Format(dtEndDate, "MM/dd/yyyy") & "','MM/DD/YYYY') "

        On Error Resume Next
        rsPRC.Close
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        rsPRC.CursorLocation = adUseClient
        rsPRC.CursorType = adOpenStatic
        rsPRC.LockType = adLockOptimistic
        rsPRC.Open strSql4 & strSql3, cnPRC
```

Comment: You are missing a `"` at the end of `strSql3 = "FROM EVENTS.ODSWIND WHERE ENDDATETIME > to_date('" & Format(dtEndDate, "MM/dd/yyyy") & "','MM/DD/YYYY') ` - or has that just been lost while posting the question?  (It should have given a VBA syntax error, rather than the error you are mentioning, so it seems more likely to be a posting issue.)

Comment: That is an error from the Oracle database you are connected to not from your VBA itself. Is this a pass-through query (it doesn't look like one)?

Comment: The thing is, the code works fine without the IIF statement, I can not get that one to work

Comment: Why do you have `IIF` inside the string?

Comment: I am sending the IIF statement to the database. The [ENDCODE] field is inside the database

Comment: I'm pretty sure, there is not an `IIF` in `Oracle Database`. And even if it would, then it would look llike `IIF(ENDCODE='6','MSNAG','0')` - note the single quotation marks and **not** double quotes. Try using [CASE Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your data type for [ENDCODE].  If it is a text field then try this:

```
strSql4 = "SELECT FWLOTID, ENDDATETIME, ENDCODE, DRAW, IIF([EVENTS].[ODSWIND].[ENDCODE]=""6"", ""MSNAG"",""0"") as IsItSix "
```

If [ENDCODE] is numeric, then try this:

```
strSql4 = "SELECT FWLOTID, ENDDATETIME, ENDCODE, DRAW, IIF([EVENTS].[ODSWIND].[ENDCODE]=6, ""MSNAG"",""0"") as IsItSix "
```

Also, let us know what database you are sending this code to.  Is it an Access Jet database?  An Access Ace database?  A SQL Server database?  All the extra info you give can let us help you better.

***EDIT***

Also... IIF will only work with an Access Sql query.

Your error looks like an Oracle error.

Assuming you are sending to Oracle, try this:

```
strSql4 = "SELECT FWLOTID, ENDDATETIME, ENDCODE, DRAW, CASE WHEN [ENDCODE]= '6' THEN 'MSNAG' ELSE '0' END as IsItSix "
```

***EDIT AGAIN***

Try this:  (if it doesn't work, let me know the exact error message.)

```
strSql4 = "SELECT FWLOTID, ENDDATETIME, ENDCODE, DRAW, CASE ENDCODE WHEN '6' THEN 'MSNAG' ELSE '0' END AS ISITSIX "
```

Comment: Not actzacltty sure what kind of database it is. I run it from Access 2003

Comment: The thing is, this code works totally fine without the IIF statement

Comment: I updated the answer to use a case statement for Oracle code.  You should still try to find out what data type [ENDCODE] is.

Comment: You need to add a space to the end of these strings to separate them from the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Thanks steve... I missed the space when reformatting.

Comment: Also Oracle SQL code normally ends with a semi-colon.

Comment: @Steve.. Lol... yes... The semi-colon could go at the end of his strSql3 line.  (Why 3 comes after 4... I don't know.  I'm assuming legacy code.)

Comment: Wait. Do I need the brackets around ENDCODE?

Comment: I think not, but you may need double quotes as it's likely to be a reserved word.

Comment: @Aleksandr, Brackets won't hurt and they usually help avoid reserve word problems.  But the real answer to your questions are too:  Find out what database you are sending your SQL code to.  Different databases use different syntax and logic structures.  Until you figure out what database it is, you are sending us all on a wild goose chase.  Also figure out what the data type is for [ENDCODE].  Knowing the data type will let you know if you need single quotes, double quotes, or no quotes at all.  Until you find out the data type, you are sending us all on a wild goose chase.

Comment: @abraxascarab So, I looked into it more. It says it has a Oracle ODBC Driver Version 10.2. Also endcode is a String data type

Comment: @Aleksandr, I simplified the above code.  Try it again.  Thanks for finding the Oracle version and data type.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  While Access SQL and Oracle SQL have lots of common structure, some commands are different based on the database.  Knowing you are sending this SQL to Oracle should help you with future programming.  Cheers. : )

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this and see if this works:

```
strSql4 = "SELECT FWLOTID, ENDDATETIME, ENDCODE, DRAW, IIF(""ENDCODE""='6', 'MSNAG','0') "    ' Or ENDCODE='10' Or ENDCODE='11' Or ENDCODE='12' Or ENDCODE='14'"
```

Comment: This gets the same error, the missing expression error

Comment: @AleksandrVoronin: Edited. Try this one maybe?

Comment: Gives me a missing parathesis error. I was also getting this error when I did not have the brackets around ENDCODE.

Comment: @AleksandrVoronin: Replace all `[` and `]` in your entire query with double-quotes.

Comment: Do I need the "[" brackets? I can run this SQL code in Access 2003 without them. @dotNET

Comment: @AleksandrVoronin:[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800337/oracle-client-requires-parentheses-around-column-names) suggests that all your column names should be enclosed in double-quotes.

Comment: Why did you ""ENDCODE"" when clearly the OP has ENDCODE as a Field?